# HTML form sends wrong product ID to be updated

Tags: php, html

I display multiple rows of data from a database about product information such as name and price and I also echo `<input type="hidden">` with the value of each product ID as stored in the database.
I echo this hidden ID value because I need to keep track of each product id because I want to be able to update the information after displaying it.

But, whenever I press the Update button near each product, the form sends the last product ID in the SQL table

This is how I display the data from the database into the HTML page:

```
<?php
$products = getAllProducts();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo
    '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $row['product_id'] .'">                                           
    <tr> 
    <td scope="row">' . $row['name'] . '</td>                                                                    
    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="' . $row['price'] . '"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>    
    <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>  
    </tr>';
}
?>
```

And some of the code in the file that takes care of the update:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $product_id = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    //$product_id always gets the latest ID in the SQL table instead of the 
    //product ID where the button was clicked in the table row    

    if (isset($_POST['update_button'])) {
    
     

    } else if (isset($_POST['delete_button'])) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All the rows have the same input names. The `$_POST` variable will contain the values from the last row.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a workaround? Or this approach is wrong?

Comment: See the duplicate question linked above

Comment: maybe you are including all the inputs (of all products) within the same form submit?

Comment: I saw it, but is there a way to know which button was clicked? Because according to the answer above, I will have to iterate over all the values and I still can't tell which one was clicked, and I want to specifically update information in the row that was clicked

Comment: try add from <?php
$products = getAllProducts();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo
    '<form><input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $row['product_id'] .'">                                           
    <tr> 
    <td scope="row">' . $row['name'] . '</td>                                                                    
    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="' . $row['price'] . '"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>    
    <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>  
    </tr></form>';
}
?>

Comment: But if I use `name=$product_id` - how can the PHP script know what to expect?